# Como transformar um inteiro em decimal?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso de uma função para fazer o seguinte, recebo o número por exemplo 15, e preciso transformar ele em um decimal 1.0, arredondando o 5 para 0.

Tentei utilizar o `number_format(15, 1, '.', '')`, porém ele me retorna 15.0

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: para fazer arredondamento você deve utilizar a função [intval()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php), veja também [outras funções matemáticas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.math.php). Uma simples divisão vai resolver o problema: `intval(15 / 10)`

Comment: Você digitou 15, que é um número inteiro. Tente mudar o número para 1.5 para testar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo assim?

```
<?php

$a = 15;
$b = $a / 10; //1,5
$c = floor($b); //1  - arredonda para baixo

var_dump($a, $b, $c); //para você verificar a transformação do número

echo number_format($c, 1, '.', ''); //para exibir '1.0'
```

outras funções para arredondamento é o [round](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php) e o [ceil](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php)

Comment: O resultado do `var_dump` é `int(15) float(1.5) float(1) `

Comment: eu sei o resultado, eu que escrevi o código. Estou mostrando a transformação do número

Comment: Adir eu sei que tu sabes o resultado, mas quem vier ver a pergunta não sabe.